# E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am using Google Sign In via Firebase in my app. But while running the published app from Play Store, it shows following error.

```
E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
```

All though I have registered on Firebase, and API Console, with ids mentioned in JSON file. Following is the JSON File code

```
{
  "project_info": {
  "project_number": "311816357497",
  "firebase_url": "https://mcqsce.firebaseio.com",
  "project_id": "mcqsce",
  "storage_bucket": "mcqsce.appspot.com"
},
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:311816357497:android:494b736XXXX6010b",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "in.readhere.mcqceit"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "311816357497-9ma34c4qXXXXXXXXXXXXXoep8b24u8g.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "in.readhere.mcqceit",
        "certificate_hash": "6847ce9f7e38dc588d12345678f21c13bd25ea7c"
      }
    },
    {
      "client_id": "311816357497-5lbqnmj0bxxxxxxxxxxxxxm4qjfhmq06.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "AIzaSyC6BGtRfxxxxxxxxxGrwwe_0V3uY9g-0dI"
    }
  ],
  "services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "311816357497-5lbqnmj0bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxm4qjfhmq06.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
       ]
     },
     "ads_service": {
       "status": 2
     }
   }
 }
 ],
 "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Following is the API Console for app
[firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QkTw.png)

[api console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bTVd.png)

Comment: getting same issue is there any solution you got ?

Comment: is your firebase and google play console account different? than please keep it similar. @JosephM

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Answer (score 51):

After spending some time I figure it out what was the problem with Google sign in and why this error was throwing when I do Google sign in.

So here is the solution for this: In my case, I have published the apk on google play store and I have selected Google play app signing what that does it will create new certificate keystore for security purpose and the old keystore get invalid (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) and you have added SHA1 in firebase for old keystore not for new one which is created by Google. So when you try logging in through google then it throws this error.

So i figure it out: Go to your Google play console(https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) > Select the App (on the left menu) > Release Management > App signing

You will see two app signing certificate one is your old uploaded keystore certificate and another one is the newly created app signing certificated created by google play. So copy the SHA1 and SHA256 key from App signing certificate and paste the same key in Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com) > Select your project > select app setting > General (Select your app package) > and paste the both SHA1 and SHA256 key and save and you are done.

Restart the app and it will work. It works in my case ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I think you just saved me hours of debugging!

Comment: hello i have more question did i must delete the last SHA1 before adding new sha-1 and  SHA256 from firebase

Comment: and did i must compile and build the game again  with new google-services.json

Comment: Hello @Abojemyeg, you can keep the old SHA1 if it is still in use otherwise you can delete and proceed with new SHA-1 and SHA256. Good Luck!

Comment: @Abojemyeg I have both of them but got the same error. But after removing the old one the issue was resolved.

Comment: @joshiparas : Please accept this answer as "accepted answer" as it is exactly what the problem was and solution is to the point as well.

Comment: Worked for me using only the API, too. (Without attaching to firebase)
Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the answer! I was already so pissed off with fixing so many release-only build errors with react native and when finally everything was working, this wasn't, lol, a simple fix!

Comment: Thanks, @ManjunathBilwar, this solved my problem after spending almost 4 hours trying to find the issue!

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please check your build variant [Release|Debug] .
Possible errors are :
you have added SHA1 for  DEBUG and you build release apk or vice versa

Answer (score 2):

You need to add SHA fingerprint for each android app on your project settings.for Firebase, edit the below link with your project's name and then add the fingerprint for your app.

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/{YOUR_PROJECT_NAME}/settings/general/
```

Comment: yes I have all ready added SHA fingerprint for the app. But still it is not working.

Comment: @joshiparas I have same problem. Please let me know if found any solution.

Comment: @Maulikpatel I had my firebase and google play account with two different emails. I started using both with same email. I didn't find any solution to the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

The complete recipe:

1. As the other answers, make sure that your actual signed Android apk has the same SHA fingerprint as what you specified in the console of your Firebase project's Android integration section (the page where you can download the `google-services.json`)
2. **On top of that** go to the `Settings` of your firebase project (gear icon right to the Overview at the top-left area. Then switch to `Account Linking` tab. On that tab link the Google Play to your project.

And voila! Hopefully your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

1)Just open below link of your google console account

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

2)select your project and done, try to login now (google automatically create credential based on your FCM project).

***Only follow 3 step if you not created project in*** [**FCM**](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/)

3)create a new Credentials / OAuth client id / Android, defined by the SHA1 fingerprint  and your APK package name. Done

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the problems was security network in my phone. I fixed by removing the security network.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SHA1 fingerprint for debug app and another one for release. Run this in a terminal to get the release fingerprint:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias <your-key-name> -keystore <path-to-production-keystore>
```

You will need your keystore password (the one you use to generate a signed APK).
Then go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/ and add the new fingerprint

I was having the same problem when trying to sign in with Google on a published app, and this fixed the problem